# nodejs json endpoint from api json stream

Tags: node.js

I am connecting to an api and pulling a set of json data. the javascript outputs the json as the variable feedData and when i include that in a html  i get the json on a html page as expected. What i want to do is output it as a json endpoint. I tried to get fancy and when i  tried:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send(feedData);
});
app.listen(3000, function () {
 console.log('posting data');
});
```

the problem is that i need to import an api.js file and when i attempt to load this i get an error related to the api.js file which is windows is not defined.  Like i said, the html

```
 document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML += JSON.stringify(feedData, undefined,2);
```

then

```
<pre id="mydiv"></pre>
```

works fine but i will also to recall every x seconds because this is a live json feed.

Currently, i just decided to connect via python, loading it into mongodb and creating a nodejs endpoint from there, which works fine,  but it seems there should be a way here.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [res.json](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json), `res.json(feedData);` to send objects. If you want to send a string just, use `res.send`

Comment: i still get the error when using node, Reference error: window is not refined which points back to the api.js file and the line for "window[JSON_REQUESTS_PROPERTY_STR] = {}"  it works fine with jquery and html, but node/ express seems to cause problems

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
res.send(feedData);
```

use

```
res.json(feedData);
```

Hope this helps